# Is it possible to modify the {u} parameter in a SharePoint Search

Tags: search

Is it possible to modify the `u` parameter of a search from the `Control_SearchBox` display template.

I want the `u` parameter to reflect where the user is e.x. in a list or in a document set so that the search starts there.

Comment: check this site http://joshmccarty.com/2010/11/create-a-sharepoint-contextual-search-box-in-a-content-editor-web-part/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by modifying the search navigation in the web you are in to point to a custom results page. It would look something like:

```
{SearchCenterURL}/contextresults.aspx?ctx={contexturl}
```

Where contextresults.aspx is the custom results page you have created in your search centre. Edit the search results web part on the custom page and select Change Query. Set the Query text to:

```
{searchboxquery} Path:{QueryString.ctx}
```

You can of course change the ctx variable to be anything you want.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response.  I think {contexturl} only provides the site url, not the url of a list you are in or the url of the document library you are in.

Comment: Yes but you could do something similar using js in the library itself.